# How can I display a locally saved image with vue.js (transformAssetUrls)?

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, bootstrap-vue

I already read about the "transformAsseturls" (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/images/) and that displaying images is possible with it, but I don´t get it (I´m new with vue.js).

So my question is: Can someone give me a step by step tutorial how to do that?

A quick answer would be very nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transformAssetUrls` is for project relative resources, which are known at compile time of your app (these are handled by webpack).

What you need, for images dynamically loaded to the server are web relative URLs (i.e. `/uploads/some-image.jpg`, where `/uploads` is a directory on the root of your server where you store dynamically uploaded images. these do not require `transformAssetUrls`, and are not handled by webpack, but rather your webserver.